# Removing data points at random

Tags: c#

I am generating a list of models simulate a day worth of data collected every minute. I want to create some other models with some data points removed randomly. Is there a way to implement this behavior? below is my code

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using MathNet.Numerics;
   using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
  public void dataGenerator()
    {
        int hrs = 24;
        int minutes = 60;
        int samplesize = hrs * minutes; // this is one day worth of data, with data created every minute
        double mean = 50;
        double stdev = 1;
        int maxmodel = 10;

        List<double[]> models = new List<double[]>();
        List<double> modelaverage = new List<double>();
        List<double> modelvariance = new List<double>();

        // generating normal models with different mean / deviations 
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxmodel; i++)
        {
            //deviations are incremented by i, to create modles of different deviations, with every model having a different center by 2*i
            double[] model = Generate.Normal(samplesize, mean + 2*i, stdev * i);

            models.Add(model);
            modelaverage.Add(model.Average());
            modelvariance.Add(model.Variance());



        }
    }
```

Comment: Just generate some random indexes between 0 and `models.Length`, removing the items at the index?

Comment: How random do you need it to be?

Comment: @hoodaticus say I want each observation to have an equal chance of being removed. In other words, each of the hrs * minutes (1440 observations) have a 50% chance of being removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following code (I think it's self-explanatory enough):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int RandomRemoveCount = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(models.Count, RandomRemoveCount); i++)
{
    models.RemoveAt(rnd.Next(models.Count));
}
```

and change `RandomRemoveCount` to how much values you want to remove. `Math.Min` is to ensure that you don't try to remove more than there is.

Comment: the code you presented seems like it is removing models at random, instead of the individual values within the model at random (which is the behavior I want. Is there a way to do it at the model level instead of the models level?

Comment: Well, you can't remove element of an array, but if you just use `List<double>` instead of `double[]` array, you can use same code (just replace `models` with `model`).
After that you can convert list to array if it is required to use array.